# Deploy SAS Jobs programmatically in 9.2 (DIS 4.2)

Tags: sas

In SAS 9.3 (DIS 4.3) there is a utility for automatically deploying SAS jobs (sas.etl.migration.batch).

Is there any way of batch deploying jobs in a 9.2 Windows environment (DIS 4.2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any way to do this automatically in DI4.2.

The closest you can get to batch deployment is to select all the jobs that you want to deploy and right click Scheduling > Deploy.